# SQL - Delete thousands of rows efficiently

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to delete thousands, even hundreds of thousands of rows from a sql server table. I have the list of primary keys in a `List<int>` object using c#. I know that using `DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (....)` will not be efficient.

Here is my entire table structure:

`ID (int, PK, clustered index)
TypeID (int, FK, no index)
SourceID (int, NO FK, no index)`

What would be the most efficient SQL to complete the task? Thanks.

Comment: Where did they come from, the values in your List<Int>, because doing it efficiently means they needed to be on the server...

Comment: Please, define efficient.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - The list of ID's come from another process in the application when it is finished with them and they can be discarded.

Comment: @DenisValeev - achieving maximum productivity with minimum wasted effort or expense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either 
1: have SQL Server determine the keys (i.e. use one or more [JOINs in your DELETE statement](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic493913-338-1.aspx))

, or if the list of keys cannot be generated purely in SQL Server,

2: get it into SQL Server using [BCP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or [BULK INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) and then JOIN to it in your DELETE statement.